# How to persist fullscreen mode in browser with autoplay like youtube playlist does?

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, fullscreen

Steps:

- Activate autoplay
- Setup fullscreen mode

When go to next video, the player exit fullscreen.
I nedeed that just like youtube, the next video of playlist keeps in fullscreen.

I know that fullscreen Browser API just accepted fullscreen mode when is triggered by a user gesture.
But, as the user has already set up full screen mode, is there a way to continue in fullscreen when going to the next video?

I also know that exits fullscreen because when go to next video, is switchted to a different page.

"In addition, navigating to another page [...] while in fullscreen mode exits fullscreen mode as well. [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

My question is, how YouTube manages to change the window.location without exiting fullscreen?

Answer (score 0):

Youtube doesn't load the next video by switching pages. It reloads/-renders the new content on the existing website.

That means that no navigation happens, and because of that, the fullscreen won't be exited.

As far as I know, they use a custom framework called [SPFJS](http://youtube.github.io/spfjs/) which stands for "Structured Page Fragments". It allows for insertion of new content in an already existing page.

Comment: The project I need to implement that, uses React, so why doesn't the Fullscreen API accept to keep the full screen mode even the React is SPA?

Comment: Single-Page-Applications (SPA) and Structured Page Fragments (SPF) are not the same thing. In case you want to change the window.location without an actual re-navigation to the new address, you might want to look at the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).